Powershell Script to delete files older than 15 days in folders
This powershell script below is not deleting files from the folders
# Set the folder paths
$folders = @(
    "C:\*_TEST\123*\Archive*\",
    "C:\*_TEST\456*\ACK*\Archive*\",
    "C:\*_TEST\789\Ack\Archive_Acks\"
)

# Loop through each folder
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    # Get all files in the folder matching the pattern
    Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File -Recurse | Where-Object {
        # Check if the file is older than 15 days
        $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)
    } | ForEach-Object {
        # Delete the file
        Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force
        Write-Host "Deleted: $($_.FullName)"
    }
}

Write-Host "Cleanup complete."

expecting this script to look in folders matching $folders but does appear to do so
Does $folder not like using *

It is a known issue:
https://superuser.com/questions/1804603/powershell-get-childitem-asterisk-wildcard-in-path-strange-behaviour-when-us
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9014

thanks alot Mike Crowley, with this info i corrected my script and its working
